# Accuracy increase but loss also increases

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am using this model.While using this model validation accuracy is  increasing but at a same time validation loss is also increasing.What happening here?

```
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.optimizers import adam

model_alpha1 = Sequential()
model_alpha1.add(Dense(64, input_dim=96, activation='relu'))
model_alpha1.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))

opt_alpha1 = adam(lr=0.001)
model_alpha1.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=opt_alpha1, metrics= 
['accuracy'])

history = model_alpha1.fit(x_train, y_train, validation_data=(x_test, y_test), epochs=200, verbose=1)
```

[image: Accuracy vs validation Accuracy]

[image: Loss vs Validation Loss]

If need any more details i will provide just comment for the detail.Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that your model is `overfitting`. In other words, your model is fitting too much for the training data and that is why it is not performing as well for the validation data anymore.

Typical way to prevent overfitting is to use `regularization` techniques. For example:

- Dropout layers https://keras.io/api/layers/regularization_layers/dropout/
- Early stopping https://keras.io/api/callbacks/early_stopping/
- Noise https://keras.io/api/layers/regularization_layers/gaussian_noise/

Try to train less deep NN for your problem or try dropout layers (or both obviously depending how these would affect). From your figure, we can see that the overfitting starts after ~25 epochs.

Overfitting may be caused, for example, by using too complex model for data set, which is not large enough. Or you just train the model too long! (here early stopping will fix the issue)

Here some regularization examples with TF: https://tensorflow.rstudio.com/tutorials/beginners/basic-ml/tutorial_overfit_underfit/

Answer (score 2):

When training a classification model, it is not possible to optimize for accuracy directly since it is not a differentiable function. Therefore, we use cross-entropy as our loss function, which is highly correlated with accuracy. When inspecting our metrics it is important to remember that these are still two different metrics.

In terms of CE loss, your model is exhibiting textbook overfitting. However, in terms of accuracy, which is what you are actually interested in, it simply "finished training". This is why we track not only the loss but also the actual metrics we are interested in in the bottom line - so that we make our decisions based on them.

Comment: can you please make some more explanation...with out ce what kind of loss function i can use here.

Comment: I think CE is the correct loss function for the task. What I'm saying is that you need to remember that CE it is not the *final metric* that are interested in. You are interested in the accuracy, and you should therefore use accuracy to decide when to stop training and which checkpoint to use.